# OptionMenu in Tkinter automatically adds brackets to options

Tags: python, tkinter

Phrases in OptionMenu display as "{Piece of cake}" instead of "Piece of cake". It happens only to multi-word strings. I made sure that strings do not have those brackets attached by replacing. When I print my list the brackets aren't there, but in OptionMenu they are. Anyone knows the reason why?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

ingredients = [('French fries', 'szt', 'D'), ('Salt', 'g', 'D'), ('Cake', 'szt', 'D'), ('Potatoes and eggs', 'g', 'D')]

chosen_ingredient = StringVar()
om_ingredients_list = OptionMenu(root, chosen_ingredient, *ingredients)
om_ingredients_list.config(width=12)
om_ingredients_list.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should extract the first item from each record (`ingredient`): `opts = [ingredient[0] for ingredient in ingredients]`.  Then pass the list to `OptionMenu(..., *opts)`.

Comment: I also need the second item in OptionMenu

Comment: Then use something like `opts = [' '.join(ingredient[:2]) for ...]`.

Comment: Thanks to your idea I managed to solve the problem:
`opts = [ingredient[0] + ' (' + ingredient[1] + ')' for ingredient in ingredients]`
worked for some strange reason. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which uses the format function to create the options.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

ingredients = [('French fries', 'szt', 'D'), ('Salt', 'g', 'D'),
               ('Cake', 'szt', 'D'), ('Potatoes and eggs', 'g', 'D')]

# Extract first and second item from tuple with format function
options = ['{} ({})'.format(*item) for item in ingredients] 
chosen_ingredient = StringVar()
om_ingredients_list = OptionMenu(root, chosen_ingredient, *options)
om_ingredients_list.config(width=20)
om_ingredients_list.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. Ingredient is an ordered dictionary. 0th element is the name of the ingredient.

Comment: Can you please post code that works and with example data which will produce the problems you describe.